# Attach and update boolean or int doesn't always work

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

Using Entity Framework 5, Given an object `messenger` that exists in the database, with bit property `published`, in previous versions of EF I would update it like this:

```
using (var c = new EFContext())
{
    Data.Messenger cm = new Messenger { MessageId = messageId };
    c.Messengers.Attach(cm);
    cm.Published = newPublishedValue;
    c.SaveChanges();
}
```

However, using EF5, this works if `newPublishedValue` is `true`, but if `newPublishedValue` is `false`, no changes are made to the database. Likewise, this pattern will not set integer values to 0.

What's going on here?

Replacing

```
c.Messengers.Attach(cm);
```

with

```
c.Entry(cm).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
```

Fixes the issue, but if EF5 won't update properties of my `new Data.Messenger` that are of a default struct value, doesn't that render the `Attach` method a bit useless?

What am I missing here?

Comment: When you attach an entity it is in Unchanged state. Does this work if you call DetectChanges() before SaveChanges()? Are you using DbContext or ObjectContext?

Comment: ah that explains it, previously we were using EF4 with objectContext, now 5 with dbContext.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It only worked in previous versions probably when you have used entities derived from `EntityObject` or POCOs with dynamic proxy change tracking. In that case the property setter is overridden with code that sets a `Modified` flag for this property when you assign a value (= call the setter) no matter what the old value was.

Using POCOs without dynamic change tracking proxies it doesn't work - for no version of EF - because the property setter is just an assignment of a data field in the entity class. Change tracking happens by snapshot change tracking which means that EF compares the values of a snapshot of the entity taken when you call `Attach` with the values the entity has when you call `SaveChanges`. If the values didn't change EF detects no changes and doesn't write an UPDATE statement for the property.

`Attach` is only for adding an entity to the context in `Unchanged` state. In your case you have to mark the property as `Modified` explicitly to ensure that it will be updated in the DB, no matter what the old value was:

```
c.Entry(cm).Property(x => x.Published).IsModified = true;
```

Comment: so using dbContext I should be using a `get-thing-from-db`, `update-thing`, `saveChanges()` pattern? doesn't this mean that there's an additional db request before an object with a known ID is updated?

Comment: @Zeus: There is no `get-thing-from-db` in my answer above. This directly causes an UPDATE statement with SET Published = value to be written.

Comment: ah yes, sorry I should be more specific - in a scenario where say you want to update 5 out of 10 db fields, it would be tidier in code to `.find()` that object in the db first, rather than set each field to `modified`. but would this be less efficient?

Comment: @Zeus: Yes, obviously, because you load the entity from the DB first. But, maybe, depending on the use case, those 50 or 100 additional milliseconds don't matter.