# Updating an Entity with EF5

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have just started a new project and having had previous happy times with Entity Framework, I Nuget'ed in the latest version. All was going well until I tried to update an entity. I have the following code;

```
using (var c = new EFContext())
{
      Data.User u = new Data.User() { UserId = UserId };
      c.Users.Attach(u);
      u.FailedPasswordAttemptCount = newFailedPasswordAttemptCount;
      c.SaveChanges();
}
```

This worked fine in EF4. However in EF5 this craps out with a DbEntityValidationException as I have a non-nullable field in the user table (UserName).

I could solve this by creating my Data.User object with an empty UserName and telling EF which properties have been modified,

```
using (var c = new EFContext())
{
      Data.User u = new Data.User() { UserId = UserId, UserName = "" };
      ...
      c.Entry(u).Property("FailedPasswordAttemptCount ").IsModified = true;
      ...
}
```

but this doesn't seem particularly manageable as more non-nullable fields are added to this and numerous other tables.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12855502/attach-and-update-boolean-or-int-doesnt-always-work/12864001) states that `Attach` will only work for entities derived from `EntityObject`. So I assume EF5 objects do not derive from this.

Anyone know how I can update my entity without having to specify the all non-nullable string fields each time.

Feels like I am missing something really obvious....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is an existing user, you could just do this...

```
c.Users.First(user=>user.UserId == UserId).FailedPasswordAttemptCount =         newFailedPasswordAttemptCount;

c.SaveChanges();
```

By the way, as an aside, in EF5 code first, entity classes don't derive from anything, but can still be attached.

Or, you go back to your way of attaching, but I think you need to turn off validation for this save, as it seems EF only validates the whole entity or nothing

```
using (var c = new EFContext()) 
{       
    c.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false; 
    Data.User u = new Data.User() { UserId = UserId };       
    c.Users.Attach(u);       
    u.FailedPasswordAttemptCount = newFailedPasswordAttemptCount;       
    c.SaveChanges(); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointer on the EF classes not being derived, Justin.

I was hoping to avoid doing what you suggest as this hits the database twice, once to select and once to update.

Comment: Its a tricky one it seems, there is a workaround by disabling validation, see update above.

Comment: If you are incrementing the FailedPasswordAttemptCount, then surely you've already performed a select for that user, to check the username and password already. Unless I'm missing something :)

Comment: Setting ValidateOnSaveEnabled on the context worked perfectly. Thanks, Justin. In most cases it makes sense to validate the properties of the user, just not in this case. Good to know that it can be turned off. 


@MarkWithers That is indeed the case, but going across multiple tiers, the DBContext is lost, hence needing to create a new one to update the count if it transpires the user has entered the wrong password ;)